# Delete Items using Input Box values

Tags: vba, outlook

I am attempting to write a macro that prompts the end-user for a number and then clears the Deleted Items folder of anything older than the specified number of days.

The code below works if I change the folder to Inbox or Sent Items.

I have tried oItems.Item(i).ReceivedTime and get the same error message.

```
Sub ClearDeletedItems()
 Dim oDeletedItems As Outlook.Folder
 Dim oFolders As Outlook.Folders
 Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
 Dim i As Long
 Set oDeletedItems = 
Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
 Set oItems = oDeletedItems.Items
 days = CInt(InputBox("How many days of Deleted Items do you want to 
 keep?"))

For i = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1
    If DateDiff("d", oItems.Item(i).SentOn, Now) > days Then
    oItems.Item(i).Delete
 End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Am getting a 438 error - Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Are you getting the same error with both `ReceivedTime` and `SentOn`? Just curious based on your comment of you tried `ReceivedTime` without success and the code shows you using the `SentOn` property

Comment: Are you getting this error in a test environment where you know that the DeletedItems folder contains only email messages? I haven't messed with Outlook and the APIs in a number of years, but if I recall correctly you can have appointments and meeting items in the deleted item folder.  Basically, in your debugging have you verified that when you see this error you are dealing with a mail item and not another type of item?

Comment: Am getting the same error with both `ReceivedTime` and `SentOn`.

Comment: The DeletedItems folder only contains mail items, I have a small amount in there for testing

Comment: And you have verified that the object you are looking at, when you get this error, is in fact a MailItem, correct?

Comment: Full disclosure - I've picked up VBA this week, beginner level. Not sure how I do that, any pointers welcome

Comment: You could step through the function in the debugger and check each value before you process it.  My suspicion of what is happening in your code is that you are hitting an item that is not a `MailItem` and so it does have the expected properties and therefore your code fails. Step through with the debugger and check what each item is or you could add an if statement to prevent looking at properties on non-MailItems.  Also, you should read up on error handling in VBA - https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#Runtime_Errors  and I recommend googling "how to debug a VBA program"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How about the following....*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim DeletedFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set DeletedFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI" _
                                  ).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)

    Dim NumDays As String
        NumDays = InputBox(prompt:="Enter the number of days", _
              Title:="Enter the number of days", Default:="Enter number here")
              Debug.Print NumDays 'Immediate Window
        If Trim(NumDays) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub


    If Not IsNumeric(NumDays) Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a numerical value."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim lngDateDiff As Long
        lngDateDiff =  Now -  NumDays
    Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "[SentOn]  < '" & Month(lngDateDiff) & _
                               "/" & Day(lngDateDiff) & _
                               "/" & Year(lngDateDiff) & "'"

    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = DeletedFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    Debug.Print Items.Count  'Immediate Window

'   // Loop through backwards
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        Debug.Print Items(i) 'Immediate Window
'       Items.Remove i ' un-comment to delete items
    Next

    Set DeletedFolder = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing seems to happen when using this, nothing deleted at all no matter what number I put in (there is a years worth of e-mail in the folder) – `Debug.Print Items.Count(i)` always comes back with 0

Comment: `Debug.Printer Filter` returns '12/31/1999' if I enter in the value of 1 at the InputBox prompt

Comment: un-commet the following line - `Items.Remove i`